# Showing snapping error in ArcGIS Online

Tags: error, snapping, arcgis-online, road

I am doing some test in ArcGIS online to know how much helpful it is for my firm, But when I opened my road line .Zip shapefile in ArcGIS online it is showing some snapping issues as well as changed the shape of the roundabouts. (road line does not have any problem in Desktop GIS softwares) Anyone can help me to know what is actually happening with files when I open it in ArcGIS Online.

---

ArcGIS Desktop

[image: Road ArcGIS Desktop]

ArcGIS Online

[image: Road ArcGIS Online]

Both are same vector file, but the first one is in ArcGIS Desktop and Second image is in ArcGIS Online.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you provide us a screen shot of your data in ArcGIS Online vs the data in desktop?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Uploading Polyline feature in ArcGIS Online](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58972/uploading-polyline-feature-in-arcgis-online) but that does not have an answer yet either so I'm not yet voting for its closure.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to have a resolution or precision problem (zoom).

1. Check your snap in ArcGIS Desktop : http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Snap/001v00000007000000/
2. Use the improved Feature Editing (Snapping to existing features in your ArcGIS Online map)
3. Export the feature from ArcGIS Online to ArcGIS Desktop to see the snapping error.

The last solution : Tchat with the ESRI's analyst ;)